# Modify WordPress plugin function in 'functions.php'

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I need to change the value of a function from a WordPress plugin that I'm using.

If I do it in the original plugin file, it works perfectly, but I'd rather make it in file *functions.php* to avoid problems on plugin update.

I need to change this:

```
public static function loop_shop_per_page() {
    return get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
}
```

Into this:

```
public static function loop_shop_per_page() {
    return '-1';
}
```

How would I go to create a filter in file *functions.php* to do just that?

Comment: which plugin are you using ?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/

Answer (score 9):

Without changing the core plugin code, I don't think you can achieve what you want.

Well written plugins usually have the `apply_filters` method called on anything that might need to be tweaked by a theme developer. As such, the plugin code *should* look something like this:

```
// Using apply_filters() to allow overriding of values...
public static function loop_shop_per_page() {
    $value = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    return apply_filters('filter_loop_shop_per_page', $value);
}
```

Then, in your *functions.php* file, you'd be able to change the value on for that by adding a filter like so:

```
add_filter('filter_loop_shop_per_page', 'mytheme_loop_shop_per_page');

function mytheme_loop_shop_per_page($value){
    return -1;
}
```

Unfortunately, unless you edit the plugin code, you probably won't be able to do what you want. You could always search the plugin for `apply_filters` to see if there's anything else you might be able to tweak to achieve the same results.

Comment: As my intention is to show all products and override posts/page. On first page load your solution worked like a charm (all products showed), but it is an AJAX filter plugin, and when filtering results, it will then show pagination and doesn't reapply the filter in functions.php. Bummer.

Comment: If you're trying to set the value globally, you could update the value stored in the database with  `update_option('posts_per_page', -1);` ?

If not, you might be able to fix using a pre_get_posts filter, or something similar. Without knowing which plugin you're using or under what circumstances you want the value to be -1, then I'm not able to help out much more than this...