# wordpress: overwrite public static function through functions.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tried this article: [Modify Wordpress plugin function in functions.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458364/modify-wordpress-plugin-function-in-functions-php) not working.

I have a plugin (Wordpress_seo). It has a folder "frontend" in it and class-breadcrumbs.php file with WPSEO_Breadcrumbs class and a public static function breadcrumb. I need to overwrite it in functions.php.

I am pretty new to wordpress, so I might have missed some solution. Here is my current code:

```
add_filter('filter_breadcrumb', 'mytheme_breadcrumb');

function mytheme_breadcrumb($before = '', $after = '', $display = true){
    if ( ! ( self::$instance instanceof self ) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        // Remember the last used before/after for use in case the object goes __toString().
        self::$before = $before;
        self::$after  = $after;

        $output = $before . '<!--1-->'.self::$instance->output.'<!--2-->' . $after;

        if ( $display === true ) {
            echo $output;

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return $output;
        }
}
```

I copied the whole function and added the '' for testing purposes, but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

thanks

Comment: Did you try to set the execution priority? To do so, add as the third parameter in the `add_filter` function the number 1000 ( this set your custom function priority to executed in the 1000th position, and possibly last ), and set as fourth parameter the number 3 ( that tells the WordPress that hook loading three parameters in the custom functions ). Also, try to die your custom function and check if your custom function is really executed.

Comment: Tried everything listed. Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you please wrap the `filter` function into another function ( name it as you like ), and then call this function using the code `add_action( 'init', 'YOUR_FUNCTION_CHOSEN_NAME' )`. If this doesn't work, I don't know what else can be the issue.

Comment: @MerianosNikos I don't see how the last comment should help, if you can explain will light me and probably others too, what is the reason for trying this?